# How to get sms data in a Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I need to have a verified phone number for my users, but after researching, there doesn't appear to be a reliable way to get the phone# from the device.  One suggestion I've seen a couple of times is to send a text message, then catch it in a Broadcast receiver and parse the phone number from the inco ming intent. I have seen this question:
[I could not get data from Intent after broadcast received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022380/i-could-not-get-data-from-intent-after-broadcast-received), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887256/sms-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-get-the-textmessage), but they do not address my problem.

Currently, I have the receiver working, but I can't get any data about the SMS message, which presumably is accessible through the intent.

Here's the code that fires when the user presses the SEND button:

```
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String SENT = "sent";
                String DELIVERED = "delivered";
                Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);

                /*Create Pending Intents*/
                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, sentIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                /* Register for SMS send action */
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        try {
      --->                  **SmsMessage[] smsMessage = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);**
                            String messageBody = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        int resultcode = getResultCode();
                        Log.d("  RESULT=", Integer.toString(resultcode));
                    }

                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                        (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) !=
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SMSActivity.this,
                            new String[] {
                                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
                            }, 1);
                }
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo.getText().toString(), null,
                                                msg.getText().toString(), sentPI, null);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

When the call to getMessagesFromIntent() is made (line in bold), an exception is thrown as listed here at "onReceive(SMSActivity.java:60):"  The Intent is not null, so it appears that "null array" is internal to getMessagesFromIntent.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
W/System.err:     at android.provider.Telephony$Sms$Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(Telephony.java:1345)
W/System.err:     at com.jdot.jsontest.SMSActivity$1$1.onReceive(SMSActivity.java:60)
W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:993)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I assume I may have a permissions related issue.  I've added this to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

I've also seen this manifest addition a few times, but I don't know how to name MyBroadcastListener, since it it isn't a class like the examples I've seen.

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastListener">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Finally, I tried the following block of code (as an alternative) in the the body of onReceive().  Though intent.getExtras() returns a Bundle, the call bundle.get("pdus") returns null so everything else fails.

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";
if (bundle != null) {
 //---retrieve the SMS message received---
 Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
 msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
 for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
      msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
      str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
              str += " :";
              str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
              str += "\n";
    }
//---display the new SMS message---
     Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My questions are:

1. Do I need the Receiver/Intent-filter block in my manifest, and if so, how do I name the listener in the first line?
2. What is the likely reason I can not receive a copy of the incoming message in onReceive(), and what should I do to correct it?
3. Do I need to send a message and "catch it" in onReceive() in order to reliably get the devices phone number, or can I request permission to read SMS from the user, and just read the first message to get the incoming phone number?

Please note that I have read through all similar questions and have not found an answer.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
registerReceiver(..., new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

You're registering that Receiver for the action you're using for the *sent* confirmation, not for the `SMS_RECEIVED` action, which is what is broadcast when a message arrives.

The *sent* `PendingIntent` is used to confirm that the message has successfully left the device. The resulting `Intent` from that will not have any message PDUs on it, which is why you're crashing.

The action you need to register an incoming SMS Receiver for is `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`, or the constant `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`, if you're compiling with API 19 or above.

---

To address the specific questions:

> 1. Do I need the Receiver/Intent-filter block in my manifest, and if so, how do I name the listener in the first line?

Registering a Receiver in the manifest will allow your app to receive messages even when it's not already running, or in the foreground. If you don't need to do that, you don't necessarily need to register in the manifest. However, if the user navigates away from your `Activity` before receiving the message, the paused `Activity` won't get the broadcast.

The "safest" way to handle it would be to register in the manifest, but there you're registering a class, not a dynamic instance. You would need to create a `MyBroadcastListener` class, and somehow notify the `Activity` from that upon receipt; e.g., using `startActivity()`, or `LocalBroadcastManager`, or some other event bus implementation, etc.

> 2. What is the likely reason I can not receive a copy of the incoming message in onReceive(), and what should I do to correct it?

As mentioned above, the `PendingIntent` passed in the `sendTextMessage()` call is for *sent* confirmation. Its resulting `Intent` won't have the incoming message on it. You just need to listen for the correct broadcast.

> 3. Do I need to send a message and "catch it" in onReceive() in order to reliably get the devices phone number, or can I request permission to read SMS from the user, and just read the first message to get the incoming phone number?

You need to actually send a message. Incoming messages won't have the recipient number attached.

Comment: THANK YOU for being so informative...very helpful!  I will give that a shot and let you know.

Comment: No problem. I just realized I neglected to mention that you should stick with the `getMessagesFromIntent()` method, if you can; i.e., at least on API 19 or above. A new `SmsMessage#createFromPdu()` overload was added in API 23 for different PDU formats, and using `getMessagesFromIntent()` will call the correct one with the appropriate arguments for the API level, so you don't have to juggle that yourself.

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate the explanations.  I modified the intent as you suggested and it works beautifully.  One question though, if I want to support API 18, I assume I should use the bundle.get("pdus") approach to parsing the message, and that "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" will still work?  I couldn't tell from your comment if it was the constant that was specific to API-19, or both.

Comment: "if I want to support API 18, I assume I should use the bundle.get("pdus") approach" - Yep, 'cause that API level won't have the `Telephony.Sms` package, so that helper method won't exist. Something like is shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816340) is what you want. As for the action `String`, it's the same `String` no matter the API level, so you could just use that literal everywhere. If you're compiling with API 19 or above (which you apparently are), the `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` field is available, and the literal value should be inlined at compile time.

Comment: I want to get both the SENT and SMS_RECEIVED broadcasts.  I assume I have to create a new IntentFilter and add both actions to it, and use this filter in the registerReceiver(..).  What I don't understand is the connection between this and the PendingIntent passed into the smsManager.sendTextMessage(...) call.  Do I need to pass both actions in that PI, or does it matter?

Comment: If you want to use the same Receiver for both actions, then yeah, you'd just add that second action to the `IntentFilter`. Make sure to check `getAction()` on the `Intent` passed into `onReceive()`, so you know how to handle a particular broadcast. The `PendingIntent` you're passing `sendTextMessage()` just needs to have your `SENT` action (it can only have one action, anyway). The `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast is generated by the system, so it constructs the `Intent` with that action. You just need to register to receive it.

Answer (score -3):

try this.Hope it will help you.

```
public class IncomingSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        if (b != null) {
            Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                        .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                        .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                if (senderNum .equals("VK-VERIFY")) 
                 {
                        MainActivity Sms = new MainActivity();
                        Log.d("TAG",""+message);
                        Sms.recivedSms(message);
                 }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nitish.incomingsms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
</uses-permission>    

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

in message variable you will get whole messagebody.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample.  It doesn't help me with my current problem, but could be useful in the future.